# Can you access PermissionSetNames from PermissionSetGroup using APEX?

Tags: apex, permission-sets, permission-set-groups

this one should be a quick one. We had a request from our Admins to use PermissionSetGroups rather than merely using the PermissionSets.

I'm messing around with it a bit and noticed that the PermissionSetGroup does not add the PermissionSets to the user. Does not appear that you can access these permissionSets 'names' from the PermissionSetGroup. Is this accurate?

I would have expected a List field on the PermissionSetGroups, but couldn't find anything online or in the docs on how to access.

Anyone else struggling with this? Anyone have any solutions?

#### IMG_Explaination:

TestGroup is the PermissionSetGroup and contains Test1 and Test2. Manually Added the PermissionSets to get them into the query results

[image: TestGroup is the PermissionSetGroup and contains Test1 and Test2. Manually Added the PermissionSets to get them into the query results]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A handy resource for understanding this is the schema doc in Salesforce Object Reference. You can see [Profile and Permission Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_profile_permissions.htm) and note that there is a junction record called `PermissionSetGroupComponent` between `PermissionSetGroup` and `PermissionSet`

So, to get a list of the component `PermissionSets` in a `PermisisonSetGroup`

```
SELECT Developername, 
  (SELECT PermissionSet.Name 
      FROM PermissionSetGroupComponents) 
 FROM PermissionSetGroup
```

Comment: cropredy, I'm not sure this query works. Its saying that there is no column When I run the query in Apex...

Comment: `List<PermissionSetGroup> psg = [SELECT Developername, 
  (SELECT PermissionSet FROM PermissionSetGroupComponents) 
                              FROM PermissionSetGroup];

System.debug(psg.size());`

Comment: you subquery is missing the `.Name`

Answer (score 0):

THanks to @cropredy for getting the schema. That's helpful, this code snippet should provide more clarity for people on the forums that are looking for the recipe to access these things.

```
List<PermissionSetGroup> psg = [
   SELECT Developername, 
          (SELECT 
            Id, 
            PermissionSet.Name 
           FROM 
            PermissionSetGroupComponents
          )
   FROM PermissionSetGroup 
   WHERE DeveloperName ='TestGroup'
];

System.debug(psg.size()); // Validate the query is getting the permission set groups

List<PermissionSetGroupComponent> comp = psg.get(0).PermissionSetGroupComponents; //Might be a more efficient way to do this next bit. . . 

System.debug(comp.Size()); // confirm that the group components junction object list was configured correctly. 

//Loop through permissionSet.Name to determine if the user has the permission sets. 
for ( PermissionSetGroupComponent c : comp ){
    System.debug(c.PermissionSet.Name); 
}
```